# Can I delete these past version folders in my user App data

Tags: versions

I'm running out of space fast on my ssd and am looking for files I can safely delete. Are these folders in the image safe to get rid of for the past versions of blender?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Each of those folders is only required for that specific version of Blender.

You only need to keep the folders for any versions of Blender that you still use. So, for example, if you no longer use version 2.65, you can safely delete that folder, etc.